# Unable to add string when printing

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out how to fix my error.

Pretty new to Python so if you can be as specific as possible, it helps.

```
print ('HStartX: ') + str(HSX)
print ('LStartX: ') + str(LSX)
print ('HStartY: ') + str(HSY)
print ('LStartY: ') + str(LSY)
print ('HendX: ') + str(HEX)
print ('LendX: ') + str(LEX)
print ('HendY: ') + str(HEY)
print ('LendY: ') + str(LEY)
```

Here is where the error occurred..

> TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for +: NoneType and 'str'

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Might want to checkout https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate a string with another string, not with the returning value of `print` (which is always `None`):

```
print ('HStartX: ' + str(HSX))
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's `print()` function doesn't return anything, so when you call `print ('string')` the result of that call is `None`. When you try to add that to your string cast, the error occurs.

You can fix this by adding strings within the print function, for example

```
print('HStartX: ' + str(HSX))
```